# If $n,k\in\mathbb N$, solve $3^k-1=x^n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If $n,k\in\mathbb N$, solve $$3^k-1=x^n$$

This seems like an interesting problem. I've currently tried a few things (one could try a lot of things in this case):

$1)$ $x^n\equiv -1\pmod 3\Rightarrow x\equiv -1\pmod 3\Rightarrow n=2r+1$, where $r\in\mathbb N\cup\{ 0\}$.

Which brings us to $3^k-1=x^{2r}x$.

$2)$ $2\mid 3^k-1$, so $x^{2r}x$ is divisible by $2$.

$3)$ By checking congruence modulo $4$, we see that $k=2m$, where $m\in\mathbb N$.

Thus $(3^m+1)(3^m-1)=x^{2r}x$. That's just a few things we could try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $n$ is odd, it has some odd prime divisor $p$, or is $1$, if it is $1$, we have an infinite family of trivial solutions. Since if we care of only prime $n$ we are done (why?), let's suppose $n=p$.

$$3^k=(x+1)(1-x+x^2-x^3\cdots)$$
And since $x\equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, the residues on the right parentheses $\pmod3$ look like
$$1+\underbrace{-2+1+-2+1\cdots}_\text{p-1 times}\equiv 1+\underbrace{1+1+1\cdots}_\text{p-1 times}\equiv p \pmod{3}$$

Therefore we want that $p$ is a multiple of $3$, therefore $p=3$

So finally we have $x^2-x+1=3(3q^2-3q+1)$. Since the parentheses is not divisible by $3$, and it must be a power of $3$, it must be $1$. So we have $3q(q-1)=0 \iff q=0,1$. $q=0$ does not work.

Therfore the only solution is $x=3q-1=2$, $n=3$, $k=2$

Comment: Shouldn't you, after having concluded that the only prime divisor of $n$ is $3$, consider the case $n=3^a$ too?

Comment: @barto It is not necessary, because I didn´t rule out $x=y^{3^{a-1}}$. That is, when I consider $n=3$, I am implicitely considering every cube, including $x^{3^a}$ .

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [Zsigmondy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem) (don't attempt to pronounce this name). This is, in some sense, weaker then Catalan's conjecture so it could be nicer to use this theorem.

An elementary proof can be found [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1997-125-07/S0002-9939-97-03981-6/S0002-9939-97-03981-6.pdf), the required result is Theorem 3. As is written on the first page: *''Except for such basic facts, the paper is self-contained.''*

I hope this is somehow satisfactory.

Comment: I'm sure there's a better proof that doesn't require Zsigmondy's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution is $k=2,n=3,x=2$, if $n>1$. We can easily see that this is a consequence of a well known theorem [Catalan's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture).

Comment: Oh, but how could we prove this without using the theorem?

Comment: Or you could show me the proof of that theorem as well if it's elementary and doesn't require calculus or something like that.