# Solutions for diophantine equation $3^a+1=2^b$

Tags: diophantine-equations

I am looking for solutions for the diophantine equation

$3^a+1=2^b$

where $a\in \Bbb N$ and $b\in \Bbb N$.

> Is there a power of $3$ that gives a power of $2$ when you add $1$?

Two solutions are easy to find:

1. $3^0+1=2^1 \rightarrow 1+1=2$
2. $3^1+1=2^2 \rightarrow 3+1=4$

But I'm looking for other solutions (solutions where $a>1$).

I believe that there is no other solution, but how can you proof this conjecture?

**More general:**
How can you find solutions for

$p_1^a+n=p_2^b$

where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are prime and $a,b,n\in \Bbb N$?

Comment: Following question addresses general case $3^a-2^b = \pm 1$ : [$|2^x-3^y|=1$ has only three natural pairs as solutions](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164874/2x-3y-1-has-only-three-natural-pairs-as-solutions)

Comment: More generally: [Can we find positive integers $a$ and $k \geq 2$ with $2^n - 1 = a^k$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714936)

Comment: @Sil there are `\pm` and `\mp` which output $\pm$ and $\mp$, respectively ;-)

Comment: @barto Thank you, updated. ;)

Comment: By the way, thanks for contributing to the network of linked questions!

Comment: Btw, the equation $p_1^a+n=p_2^b$ can be considered as a particular case of Pillai's equation. You can check these links: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1642096/special-case-of-pillais-conjecture and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29677/is-there-a-solution-for-the-equation-xm-yn-k-in-which-k-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$3^a=2^b-1$$
Let $b=2k, k \in \mathbb N, k \ge 1$
$$3^a=(2^k-1)(2^k+1)$$
Then

$$2^k-1=3^l$$
$$2^k+1=3^m$$
where $m+l=a, m>l$
Then $$3^m+3^l=2^{k+1}$$
$$3^l(3^{m-l}+1)=2^{k+1}$$
Then $l=0, k=1, m=1$

2) Let $b=2k+1$. Then  $2^b≡2 (\mod 3)⟹a=0 $

Comment: Also, if $b=2k+1$, you have $2^b \equiv 2\ (\textrm{mod}\ 3) \implies a=0 $

Comment: @Baconaro: Thank you!

Comment: I miss the general part of my question: How does your answer help me to find solutions for 3^a+5=2^b (27+5=32 is one solution for this)?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: consider the powers of $3$$\pmod 8$. We have $3^1\equiv 3\pmod 8$ and $3^2\equiv 1\pmod 8$. So by induction it follows that $3^{2k+1}\equiv 3\pmod 8$ and $3^{2k}\equiv 1\pmod 8$, for $ k\in\Bbb {N} $. So $3^a+1$ would be  congruent with $4$ or $2$$\pmod 8$. Therefore we deduce that if $3^a+1=2^b $, then $ b\le 2$.

If $ b=2$, then $ a=1$.

If $ b=1$, then $ a=0$. Hence all the solutions are the pairs $(a, b)=(0,1), (1,2) $.